# Make default value in switch based on condition in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have some code that looks like this

```
if (case1) {
  this.needHelpFileName = case1;
} else {
  if (case2) {
    this.needHelpFileName = case2;
  } else {
    this.needHelpFileName = 'general';
  }
}
```

You will see that there is some lot of if and else, not so good readable, i have tried to make in switch like this, but I didnt have luck, anyone got solution with switch statement?

```
switch (this.needHelpFileName) {
  case case1:
    return this.needHelpFileName = case1;
  case case2:
    return this.needHelpFileName = case2;
  default:
    return this.needHelpFileName = 'general';
}
```

The problem is that values can be sometimes undefined?

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your if else statements lik below:

```
this.needHelpFileName = 'general'; // initialize with default value

 // Assign value as per condition.
  if (case1) {
    this.needHelpFileName = case1;
  } else if(case2) {
    this.needHelpFileName = case2;
  }
```

Comment: Ok, I see, is it possible to make it in switch?

Comment: I would suggest you to not use the switch as it does not serve the purpose here. We want to execute some part of the code when the condition evaluates to true. And switch should not be used for that.